# C# - Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, winforms, boolean, backgroundworker

Sorry it's similar to other posts but I've read similar posts for an hour, and reviewed/re-reviewed my code but I just can't see where it does not return a value. Any assistance appreciated.

```
public static bool UploadLog()
        {
            var uploader = new BackgroundWorker();
            uploader.DoWork += delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
                Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
                Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
                Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
                Data["api_option"] = "paste";

                WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);
                    string response;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                    {
                        Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                        e.Result = false;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        e.Result = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                    e.Result = false;
                }
            };
            uploader.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

**Edit:** I have already tried running this function as `async` but it resulted in locking up the UI, hence running this in a background worker.

Comment: Immediately after `uploader.RunWorkerAsync();`, there isn't a return value.

Comment: `Not all code paths return a value` I think that you'll find there are actually *no* code paths that return a value here.

Comment: Abion47 is completely right :)

Comment: There is no `return`in the method...or you must add one, or change the method signature to `public static void UploadLog()`

Comment: The compiler expect that your method will return a boolean but at the moment your function return nothing (void). Return a boolean at least at the end of your function and the compiler will not raise this error again

Comment: You method declaration states a bool return value. _public static **bool** UploadLog()_, therefore, all your code paths must return a bool. By code path.... all "exit points" of your method must return a value. Unless you change "bool" to "void" which would simply mean your method does not return a value.

Comment: From a design standpoint, you should change your method to be `void` anyway. My understanding of what you are trying to do is to return whether or not the async process completed successfully. In order to do that, though, you would have to wait for the process to complete, which defeats the purpose of calling it asynchronously. Instead, you should ignore the worker entirely and let it do its thing, then use the `worker.RunWorkerCompleted` event to check whether it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments pointed back to looking at using `async` instead of a background worker. I read up a bit more on this and revisited my code and it is now working successfully, and not locking up the UI either. :)

My now working code:

```
public static async Task<bool> UploadLog()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
            Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
            Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
            Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
            Data["api_option"] = "paste";

            WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);
                string response;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                    return false;

                }
                else 
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    return true;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                return true;

            }
        }
```

My button to call the code:

```
private async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.btnUpload.Enabled = false;
            this.btnUpload.Text = "Uploading...";

            var uploaded = await Task.Run(Pastebin.UploadLog);

            this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
            this.btnUpload.Enabled = true;

            if (uploaded == true)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl);
                MessageBox.Show("Your logfile has been uploaded to Pastebin successfully.\r\n" +
                    "The URL to the Paste has been copied to your clipboard.", "Upload successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The upload of your logfile to Pastebin failed.", "Upload failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a function to return a `bool` (see function definition), you will have to return one at least somewhere in your code. Add `return true;` right after `uploader.RunWorkerAsync ();`. This will do the job.

A better possibility would be to make the function `async` or to use `void` as a return type.

Comment: It makes sense, at least for the code above. There is no dependency on a boolean value, so `true` will do. A `void` return type for the function would be the better choice here, I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. If you are going to return `true` no matter what happens, then the method should be `void`

Comment: That's exactly what I said.

Comment: No need to be condescending to the OP with your first line.. *You say that you've read similar posts for an hour, still there is not a single return statement in your code.*.. You nor I know for sure if the OP is telling the truth or not.. so lets not **assume** that they're lying and put them down for it.  This is supposed to be a supportive community.

Comment: @Pikoh, while I agree with first comment I can't agree with you. I have methods what return `true` no matter what. ;)

Comment: @Sinatr well..of course you can have them, but may you explain what's the point in doing so? :)

Comment: I did try making the function `async` and it did work, however had the side effect of locking the UI up until the upload had completed, hence trying to get it work with a background worker.

Comment: @Pikoh, actually I lied, they always return [false](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/21/exception-filters-in-c-6/)..

Comment: @Rawns If you made your function async and it locked up the UI, you messed up somewhere. I'd suggest trying that again, because having an asynchronous process is mostly better dealt with by using an asynchronous function.

Comment: @NikxDa While that is generally true, where a `BackgroundWorker` is involved I would recommend subscribing to its `RunWorkerCompleted` event instead. On a side note, I imagine that it locked up OP's UI thread because he called the method with `async` and then immediately asked for the result.

Comment: @Sinatr well,that's a complete different case but thank you, I did learn something new ;)

Comment: @Abion47 You're correct, but I also see no need for a background worker here. This is achievable whilst only using async methods.

Comment: @NikxDa - Thanks for the feedback. I revisted Async and have got it working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You method declaration states a bool return value. `public static bool UploadLog()`, therefore, all your code paths must return a bool. By code path.... all "exit points" of your method must return a value. Unless you change "bool" to "void" which would simply mean your method does not return a value.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// With return bool
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool UploadLog()
    {
        var didItWork = true;//here's a return value you could use. Initialize to true

        var uploader = new BackgroundWorker();
        uploader.DoWork += delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
            Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
            Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
            Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
            Data["api_option"] = "paste";

            WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);
                string response;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                    e.Result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    e.Result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                e.Result = false;
                didItWork = false;//did not work, so set the return value accordingly
            }
        };
        uploader.RunWorkerAsync();

        return didItWork;//return the result

    }
```

OR

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Drop the return value by making it void instead of bool
    /// </summary>
    public static void UploadLog()
    {
        var uploader = new BackgroundWorker();
        uploader.DoWork += delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
            Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
            Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
            Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
            Data["api_option"] = "paste";

            WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);
                string response;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                    e.Result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    e.Result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                e.Result = false;
                didItWork = false;//did not work, so set the return value accordingly
            }
        };
        uploader.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the first option will virtually always return true every time regardless of the result of the worker since the worker thread probably won't even have time to start (much less get executed to the point of completion) by the time the main thread has returned the value of `didItWork`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I think I can see now that I'm maybe going the wrong way about this with not wanting to lock the UI up for the end user, while at the same time wanting to wait for a success or failure failure result.